# What was Ryan holding near the start of Doctor Who S11E1?

Tags: plot-explanation, props, doctor-who

In Series 11, Episode 1 of Doctor Who, entitled "The Woman Who Fell To Earth", there's a scene near the start with Ryan holding an object. Here's a screen clip taken a little over 3 minutes from the start.

[image: Ryan holding the object]

In the scene, a series of geometric shapes appears in the air, and later a solid object appears. Ryan holds a reddish, flashing object in his hand after 'touching' the shapes and before the solid object appears. He doesn't seem to be holding the object before approaching the shapes, nor does he have it in his hand after the solid object appears.

(Spoiler alert)

> The object resembles a 'return circuit' appearing later in the episode, but it hasn't been introduced or found yet at this point in the story and there's no explanation for how Ryan got hold of it. Maybe it materialised when he pushed the 'button', or it might have just been the actor grabbing a prop at the wrong time. With Doctor Who, seemingly unintentional stuff sometimes turns out to be intentional.

What is Ryan holding? How did he get it, where did it go, and does it have anything to do with the circuit from later in the show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's his rear bike light.

[image: Standard UK set of bike lights]

[image: Shot of his bike with the light attached]

However, every shot before and after this shows his left hand is empty. Probably a simple continuity error and they cut the shot where he picked it up from under the tree. Looks like he then puts it in his jacket pocket when approaching the pod.

Comment: Haha - that's plausible!

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the image in the question, by the way. With the better pictures, I can see that the shape matches. The physical features are a bit odd, but it could fit if Ryan was showing the back of the light. The flashing also fits.

Comment: The model he's holding isn't exactly the one I've got an image of, but they're both pretty common in the UK. It's also a bit overexposed so you cannot see the three LEDs, which catch the light in the scene. The back of the light would be opaque black plastic.